# Unit test hangs forever if `DoFn` resets event timers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm unit testing (with `TestStream` and `PAssert`) a `DoFn` that resets event timers. Test hangs forever if `DoFn` resets timers and this behavior seems specific to event domain timers.

Is this a bug in beam testing facilities or expected timer behavior?

Here is a toy example that I can reproduce this behavior with beam 2.3 SDK.

```java
static class KeyElements extends DoFn<String, KV<String, String>> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        final String[] parts = context.element().split(":");
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            context.output(KV.of(parts[0], parts[1]));
        }
    }
}

static class TimerDoFn extends DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>> {
    @TimerId("expiry")
    private final TimerSpec timerSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME);

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context, @TimerId("expiry") Timer timer) {
        timer.set(context.timestamp().plus(Duration.standardHours(1)));
        final KV<String, String> e = context.element();
        context.output(KV.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + "_output"));
    }

    @OnTimer("expiry")
    public void onExpiry(OnTimerContext context) {
        // do nothing
    }
}

@Rule
public TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

@Test
public void testTimerDoFn() {
    TestStream<String> stream = TestStream
            .create(StringUtf8Coder.of())
            .addElements(
                    TimestampedValue.of("a:0", new Instant(0)),
                    TimestampedValue.of("a:1", new Instant(1)),
                    TimestampedValue.of("a:2", new Instant(2)),
                    TimestampedValue.of("a:3", new Instant(3)))
            .advanceWatermarkToInfinity();

    PCollection<KV<String, String>> result = p
            .apply(stream)
            .apply(ParDo.of(new KeyElements()))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new TimerDoFn()));

    PAssert.that(result).containsInAnyOrder(
            KV.of("a", "0_output"),
            KV.of("a", "1_output"),
            KV.of("a", "2_output"),
            KV.of("a", "3_output"));

    p.run();
}
```

The above test would halt if input elements are `a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the timer? What kind of behavior do you expect?

Comment: @Lara I'm trying to garbage collect some states. Since I'm using global windows, states are not automatically GC'ed by the runner. I'm using timers to achieve that. However, this shouldn't matter. In the code sample I provided even if the callback is empty, the test still hangs forever.

Comment: It should work fine so I am not sure what the problem is. I'll attempt to reproduce it and see if I can see anything wrong.

Comment: @LaraSchmidt Can you reproduce this issue?

Comment: I was and I passed it to those who created the code surrounding apache beam tests. Hopefully they can update this if they find something.

Comment: Here's a link to the JIRA with my repro.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3880